# Embed image in excel xlsx zip and then reference it

Tags: excel, vba

I need to embed an image in an excel file, not place it in a sheet or book, but into the .xlsx file itself.

I then need to be able to reference it in VBA.

I can open the file with 7zip and place the image.png file in  ./xl/media and save.

How do I then reference that image in VBA?

Comment: Reference it for what?

Comment: I could be wrong but there is no direct way to work with that image. You will have to create a copy of the file, rename it to .Zip, unzip it to a temp folder and then read it from the `/xl/media` folder. The easiest is to put the images in a worksheet and hide the worksheet.

Comment: Base64-encode >> Store as CustomXmlPart